# Faster/more efficient Live Search with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs which have various data in a text input boxes.

I have a working "Live Search" where, as a user types information into an `input` box, the divs are filtered until only matching ones are shown or none at all.

However, when there are lots of rows, the responsiveness becomes sluggish and typing in the search terms is slow.

Is there a faster or more efficient method?

**Code**

```
$('input#create-row-name').keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val()!==''){
        liveSearch();
    } else $('div#rows>div.column>div.row').show();
});

function liveSearch(){
    var searchTerm = $('input#create-row-name').val().toString().toLowerCase();
    $('div#rows>div.column>div.row').each(function(){
        var searchResult = $(this).find('div.input-group>input.row-name').val().toString().toLowerCase();
        if(searchResult.indexOf(searchTerm)>=0){
            $(this).show();
        } else $(this).hide();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cache values. Remove jQuery in the critical sections.

```
var $rows = $('div#rows>div.column>div.row');
var texts = $rows.map(function () {
    return $(this).find("div.input-group > input.row-name").text().toLowerCase();
}).toArray();

$('input#create-row-name').on("keyup paste drop", function () {
    var searchTerm = $.trim( this.value.toLowerCase() ), 
        lastTerm = $(this).data("lastTerm"),
        i, found;

    if (searchTerm === lastTerm) return;
    $(this).data("lastTerm", searchTerm);

    for (i = texts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        found = searchTerm === '' || texts[i].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
        $rows[i].style.display = found ? "" : "none";
    }
});
```

It is absolutely sensible to make the search wait until the user has finished typing instead of running it *immediately* after every keyup event. I recommend a [debounce function like the one Sugar.js provides](http://sugarjs.com/api/Function/debounce).

Also (as a general tip, not so relevant here due to caching): Keep in mind that overly specific selectors are less efficient. `div#rows > div.column > div.row` is computationally more expensive than - but probably equivalent to - `#rows .row`.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this

Comment: @freefaller People tend to forget that there is an actual DOM to work with when they have jQuery. Especially for simple tasks showing/hiding an element there is no reason to use jQuery when speed matters.

Comment: Does this work when the list of rows is constantly being updated by the user? `$rows` won't include any rows added after the page has loaded surely?

Comment: The above is about as fast as it gets with static content (short of an actual search-term-to-result cache, which would speed up things considerably for re-used search terms). For dynamic content you would *either* have to abandon the caches entirely, *or* (and that's what I would do) update the caches in response page changes. This is also rather easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than go through the list on every single key-press, put a tiny delay in there so that if somebody types multiple character in quick succession it doesn't do it every time.  (This is a trick that somebody told me about years ago.)

So, for example, something like this (untested)...

```
var keyupTimer = -1;
$('input#create-row-name').keyup(function(e){
    if ($(this).val()!==''){
        if(keyupTimer != -1)
            window.clearTimeout(keyupTimer);
        keyupTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
            liveSearch();
            keyupTimer = -1;
        },200);
    } else $('div#rows>div.column>div.row').show();
});
```

This will run the `liveSearch` after 1/5th of a second, enough to allow a normal typist to press a few keys before your code does its work.

---

*Update*

As commented by @Halcyon, the above is fine if the code that is being run in the timer is already optimised... and as he also pointed out, your code is not.

Rather than try and write something new, I would advise you first use the answer provided by @Tomalak and @Halcyon... and if you still need improvments, try using my suggestion.

Comment: I was just about to post something similar.  I've found the sweet spot to be about 750ms for a live search, but any delay is going to stop that event.  Basically you're not grabbing results until the user stops typing at that point, although the 200ms timer would make it "more live".

Comment: I guess @MaKR that it depends on exactly on exactly what work will happen when the timer fires, in particular the number of rows, etc.

Comment: This solution is fine if there is nothing left to optimize, which in is certainly not the case here.

Comment: Sugar.js is a nice library that (amongst many other useful ones) provides a `debounce()` function that does exactly that. http://sugarjs.com/api/Function/debounce

Answer (score 1):

jQuery lookups are notoriously slow. See if you can optimize them. You can build an index like:

```
(function () {
    var index = new WeakMap();

    $('input#create-row-name').keyup(function(e){
        if($(this).val()!==''){
            liveSearch();
        } else $('div#rows>div.column>div.row').show();
    });

    // build index once initially
    $('div#rows>div.column>div.row').each(function(i, o){
        index.set(o, $(this).find('div.input-group>input.row-name'));
        // maybe even cache `.val().toString().toLowerCase()`?
    })

    function liveSearch(){
        var searchTerm = $('input#create-row-name').val().toString().toLowerCase();
        $('div#rows>div.column>div.row').each(function(i, o){
            // use index here
            var searchResult = index.get(o).val().toString().toLowerCase();
            if(searchResult.indexOf(searchTerm)>=0){
                $(this).show();
            } else $(this).hide();
        })
    }
}());
```

This should significantly speed up your code.

Comment: Cross-browser WeakMap support is so-so at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Making only small JQuery based alterations this is what i arrived at.

```
$('input#create-row-name').keyup(function(e){
    var text=$(this).val().toString().toLowerCase();
    if(text!==''){
        liveSearch(text);
    } else $('div#rows>div.column>div.row').show();
});

function liveSearch(searchTerm){   
    $('#rows input.row-name').each(function(){
        var searchResult = $(this).val().toString().toLowerCase();
        var $divHide=$(this).closest("div.row");
        if(searchResult.indexOf(searchTerm)>=0){
            $divHide.show();
        } else $divHide.hide();
    })
}
```

The alterations i have made are

- Reuse the textbox value between function defention.
- Optimised selectors to [reduce specificity](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/#avoid-excessive-specificity)
- Directly Looping through all inputs to find values and then finding and hiding corresponding parents instead of looping through Divs and scanning for values in them
- Could say i have cached values in places

Other better answers appeared as i was typing this one, i would suggest them over mine. I am just trying to submit my solution as well.

Comment: Kay, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: *Making only small... alterations*  - it helps if you explain what those alterations are, and why you've made them - otherwise people have to work out what your changes are